# Is the unique solution of autonomous ODE infinitely differentiable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lipschitz-functions

Consider the ODE
\begin{align}
y'&=f(y)\\
y(0)&=y_0
\end{align}
where $f$ is Lipschitz and, if it matters, always positive. 
When restricted on an interval $[0,a]$, is the unique solution of such ODE infinitely differentiable? If not, under which assumptions would this be true?

Comment: Assuming $y(t)$ is defined over an open interval of time, and $f$ is infinitely differentiable, we get $y'' = f'(y)y'=f'(y)f(y)$, $y''' = f''(y)y'f(y) + f'(y)f'(y)y' = f''(y)f(y)f(y)+f'(y)f'(y)f(y)$ and so on. In general the $n$th derivative of $y$ is a polynomial function of $f(y), f'(y), ... f^{(n-1)}(y)$. So $y$ is infinitely differentiable (over the open interval where it is defined) whenever $f$ is.